# Splitting up a matlab table in vectors

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

i'm fairly new to matlab and i'm looking for a way to evaluate data in a table. There's an excel table as illustration attached.

My measurements are savedin a txt-file divided by cycle numbers. All data is in one table though. Eventually i want to divide the data in the table in a way that i can select/use/plot the data from all columns depending on their cycle number.

E.g. plotting R and I values of cylce 2 against each other.

What's the best way to do that? I heard of timeseries, didn't find the right material online to get my head behind it yet though.

Thanks and cheers!

[image: table for illustration]

Answer (score 2):

You only need a [`table`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html). There are several ways to extract a column from a table. The simplest way is to use a dot with the name of the column. If the column has numerical values, this gives you the corresponding numerical vector.

To select some values of those vectors you can use [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html):

```
t = table; % crete empty table
t.R = [5 6 7 12 13 14 20 21 22].'; % create and fill a column of the table
t.I = [1 2 3 6 8 9 8 7 6].';
t.Cycle_Number = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3].';
ind = t.Cycle_Number==2; % logical index
plot(t.R(ind), t.I(ind))
```

To directly create the table from data contained in a file you can use [`readtable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html).